# How to put input fields on table headers without changing columns widths?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap table to show a list with many columns with different sizes. All was well, but my customer asked to include a input field in the header of the columns. This field, when filled, would perform a filter on the column.

The problem is that inserting the input field messes with column width. In consequence, now each row has a greater height due to text breadlines.

I need the input fields weight to obey column size and that the column width remain as if the input field was not there.

The original code is more or less like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div container>

   <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm small">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project </th>
                <th>Line </th>
                <th>Code </th>
                <th>Pay Item </th>
                <th>Code </th>
                <th>Material </th>
                <th>Accept. </th>
                <th>Test </th>
                <th>Status </th>

                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td>10D276 </td>
                <td>0020 </td>
                <td>203.30 </td>
                <td>EARTH BORROW </td>
                <td>703.02</td>
                <td>Earth Borrow</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>AG-COMP-15</td>
                <td>11</td>               
                <td>
                    <a href="# " class="zoom"><i class="material-icons" title="Show">zoom_in</i></a>    
                    <a href="# " class="zoom"><i class="material-icons" title="Action">directions</i></a>    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10D276 </td>
                <td>0510 </td>
                <td>580.20 </td>
                <td>RAPID SETTING CONCRETE REPAIR MATERIAL WITH COARSE AGGREGATE </td>
                <td>780.04</td>
                <td>Rapid Set Concrete Material with C. Agg</td>
                <td>Appd</td>
                <td>None_1</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="zoom"><i class="material-icons" title="Show">zoom_in</i></a>   
                    <a href="#" class="zoom"><i class="material-icons" title="Action">directions</i></a>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've just put the table inside a form and put the input field inside the headers

```
    <form>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm small">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Line  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Code  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Pay Item  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Code  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Material  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Accept.  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Test  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Status  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
                <th>Actions </th>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option I see here is to set fixed width value to the columns with css.

```
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:5%;">Project  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" > </th>
```

This will shrink the input fields to your customizable size.

Comment: Thank you! The best would be to make Bootstrap adjust the fields to the table and not the other way around. I do not like leaving fix percentages in code, but your solution works. I will do this for now.